# copy/paste HTML5 console in Openstack Horizon

Tags: openstack

Could an isolated Horizon interface be modified (or plugin developed) to support copy/paste to a server considering only nova-novncproxy is configured?

I am using an older version of Horizon provided by my public IaaS Openstack that does not allow me to copy/paste into the console.

I would like to consider hosting the latest Horizon connecting to my tenancy via API only. (no public Admin)

```
nova get-spice-console <server> spice-html5
```

ERROR (ClientException): Unknown Error (HTTP 500) -Indicates that Spice in not configured

```
nova get-vnc-console <server> "xvpvnc"
```

returns a loopback (incorrectly configured)

I have control of the VMs, but not the Openstack infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

SPICE is required on the Openstack Installation to enable copy/paste

```
nova get-spice-console <server>
```

Without SPICE, a html5 ssh gateway with an SSO solution might provide a solution to integration within Openstack Dashboard

http://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide-cloud/compute-remote-console-access.html